# In ActionScript, is it possible to call a function on a Class that applies to all instances of that class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, design-patterns

So - I have a bunch of instances of a class and there's a function I want to call on all of them. I'm wondering if rather than loop through every instance that I have, is there some way I can declare a function on the class that when called runs on each instance? For example - if my class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass{

    public var variable:String = "";

    public function MyClass(){}

    public function myFunction():void{
       this.variable = "BLORE";
    }
}
```

and I have a bunch of these:

```
var class1:MyClass = new MyClass();
var class2:MyClass = new MyClass();
```

is there a way I can call `MyClass.myFunction()` and have it called on all of my instances?

I don't know if I'm explaining this well...but there it is. I'd love any suggestions you have that don't just involve "put your instances in an array or vector and loop through them like a real man."

Comment: If all you want is to set a variable in all instances (as your example does), use a `static` variable. But I guess you want something more involved?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to change the visual state of each instance (alpha, x, etc...) using one global call. Static wouldn't work for me in this situation. :(

Comment: So you want to set a specific variable (alpha, x, y etc) for all classes at once with just one call?

Comment: Right - no matter how many or how few classes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to accomplish this:

```
package {
    public class Example {
        public static var instances:Array;

        public function Example() {
            if ( !instances ) {
                instances = [];
            }
            instances.push( this );
        }

        public static function setPropertyOnAll( property:String, value:Object ):void {
            var l:uint = instances.length;
            for ( var i:uint = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
                instances[i][property] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you have a static array within your class and you push each instance of that class into the array upon instantiation. Then you just loop through the array and change the property.

Keep in mind a few things:

- There is no error handling if the `property` does not exist. So be sure that the property you pass in `setPropertyOnAll` is actually a property or you add some kind of error check to be sure.
- Saving each instance into the array will make them ineligible for garbage collection. This is very bad, obviously. If you do do this, you'll want to create a way to remove each instance from the array, even if it has to be manually done each time. I did not do this because it is impossible to know how/when to run it or what your class structure looks like, so it will be something you need to figure out. You **do not** want to keep them ineligible for garbage collection

Comment: Ok this is great. So we can't away from the "looping through an array" issue but this seems like a really nice way to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, there is no real way around that unfortunately. You have to access them all in some fashion and a loop is really the only way to do this. Unless the Array is gigantic, you shouldn't have speed issues. Speaking of which, you should use a Vector in this case for `instances` instead of Array.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as using a `static` function that uses a `static` `Array` with references to all instances of that class.

Every time you call the class constructor to create a new instance, you need to add a reference of the instance into the `Array`

```
arrayOfInstances.push(this);
```

Then your `static` function would loop the array and do whatever you need.

Don't forget to add some static method to remove all references in the `Array` so the garbage collector can clean those objects from memory.

Comment: So you accepted Josh's answer because he posted the code (doing exactly what I said first)?

Comment: Hi Pier - sorry, I mean no offense. When I checked in you both had answered and Josh's answer was a more complete response IMO so I chose it.

Comment: I really didn't think you needed the actual code for such a simple thing. Next time you can check the exact time by putting your cursor over the "2 days ago" label. (My answer was written 2 hours earlier btw)